# Is it standard to try to send mail to the A DNS record if there is no MX record?

Tags: domain-name-system, email

Our systems cannot send e-mail to a company that has no MX record. There is an SMTP server running on their IP address and they are able to get e-mail from gmail. Is it normal for mail systems to try to connect to a SMTP server at the A record when there is no MX?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is standard, per [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321). Please see the Wikipedia page on [MX Records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record#History_of_fallback_to_A)

Comment: and it has been standard ever since RFC 821 too.  This also means that if you don't have MX records and insist on having a website without the 'www' prefix then that server will get inbound SMTP attempts too :(

Answer (score 0):

Normally yes, if no MX record exists, the A record should be used as a failsafe.

Comment: It's not a "failsafe".  Originally mail was delivered to hosts (via A records) and _then_ MX records were invented to say "actually, send it somewhere else instead...".